# Magento error: call to member function on a non-object

Tags: php, magento

I have this error message:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object in /home/autoco/public_html/shop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php on line 225

How to fix this?

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Becker_Tec>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Becker_Tec>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <tec>
            <class>Becker_Tec_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>tec_resource</resourceModel>
            <tec_resource>
                <class>Becker_Tec_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <manufacturers>
                        <table>tof_manufacturers</table>
                    </manufacturers>
                </entities>
            </tec_resource>
        </tec>
    </models>
</global>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <becker_tec>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Becker_Tec</module>
                <frontName>tecdoc</frontName>
            </args>
        </becker_tec>
    </routers>
 </frontend>
</config>
```

**Model class:**

```
<?php
class Becker_Tec_Model_Manufacturers extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{

  protected function _construct()
   {
    $this->_init('tec/manufacturers');
   }
  public function test(){
    $this->getCollection()->load(15);
  }

}
```

**Resource class:**

```
<?php

class Becker_Tec_Model_Resource_Manufacturers extends    Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract {

  protected function _construct()
   {
    $this->_init('tec/manufacturers', 'tof_manufacturers_id');
   }

}
```

**Test Page:**

```
<?php

require_once("app/Mage.php");

Mage::app();

$data = Mage::getModel("tec/manufacturers");
$data->load(136);
print_r($data);
```

Comment: you should ask the question first, then put all the code. I don't like having to browse all the way down before knowing if I want to answer or not :)

Comment: This error because Magento doesn't create model object(Mage::getModel("tec/manufacturers")). The reasons can be different, check if model file isset in path app/etc/{codepoll}/Becker/Tec/Model/Manufacturers.php

Comment: ok, so how can I fix it?

Comment: I further edited your question, notice the title which is now much more specific and the formatting of your error message

Comment: @sergio How can I check?

Comment: Post to answer location of your module files.

Comment: app/code/local/Becker/Tec

Comment: app/etc/Becker_Tec.xml

Comment: @sergiu are ok this path

Comment: @user2838459 - not sure if it was just a typo, but I don’t know if `app/etc/Becker_Tec.xml` will get picked up when Magento scans for modules. The normal location to define a module is `app/etc/modules/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<tec_resource>
```

Was the culprit as it didn't recognize how to hook up your call.

First of all use the same naming convention to avoid driving yourself mad.

Config xml model section:

```
<models>
    <becker_tec>
        <class>Becker_Tec_Model</class>
        <resourceModel>becker_tec_resource</resourceModel>
    </becker_tec>
    <becker_tec_resource>
        <class>Becker_Tec_Model_Resource</class>
        <entities>
            <becker_tec>
                <table>becker_tec</table>
            </becker_tec>
        </entities>
    </becker_tec_resource>
</models>
```

Model Class:

```
class Becker_Tec_Model_Tec extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract 
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init( 'becker_tec/tec' );
    }
```

Resource class:

```
class Becker_Tec_Model_Tec_Resource_Tec extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init( 'becker_tec/tec', 'entity_id' );
    }
```

Collection class: ( If you want to use built in collection mechanisms )

```
class Becker_Tec_Model_Tec_Resource_Tec_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init( 'becker_tec/tec' );
    }
```

Place them in the appropriate folders and you'll be able to call:

```
$oTec = Mage::getModel( 'becker_tec/tec' );
```